# nested layouts or use a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nestedlayout

in terms of performance, what will be considered better.
having nested layouts (2-3 nested layouts, reused with  tag> or using Recyclerview?

Does it matter if the layout is part of an item in another Recyclerview?

In terms of updating the data when something changes?

The number of items\layouts is static (2), so there's no way it will become larger in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: probably impossible to answer, depends on what you're doing, but i don't see the point in using a recycler if you don't plan on creating a scrolling list of content. either way i doubt this would make enough of a difference in performance to actually care about it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need using `ConcatAdapter` in `RecycleView` when scroll mutil view type. Beside you can using mutil-type, custom header, footer. Good luck :D

Comment: Instead of just telling what they can use, I suggest you to read [answer], and add explaination of why this should help them, and add a sample code.